# Selenium with Microsoft Edge driver never finishes initialising

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge

I'm using the C# bindings for Selenium and trying to get a simple automated test in Microsoft Edge working.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
        options.PageLoadStrategy = EdgePageLoadStrategy.Eager;
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.Url = "http://bing.com/";
    }
}
```

But the program halts on the initialisation of the EdgeDriver, the edge browser launches but the url never changes to "bing.com".

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: What `selenium` package version do you have installed?

Comment: @alecxe I am currently using the version 2.53.0 c# bindings

Comment: Make sure you have downloaded `edgeDriver` which is compatible with your `Os build number`.....to check you os build number use this command `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Version"`

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue. I followed the below steps to resolve it :-

Download the correct [`Microsoft WebDriver`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) server version for your build.

How to find your correct build number :-

1- Go to **Start > Settings > System >** About and locate the number next to OS Build on the screen. This is your **build number**. Having the correct version of WebDriver for your build ensures it runs correctly.

2- Run this command `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Version"` this will give the output like `OS Version:                10.0.10586 N/A Build 10586`. Here is build number is `10586`

You need to check your **Windows OS** `build number` and [`download`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) appropriate `.msi` and install it.

Provide the `Syetem` property where `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` installed to `webdriver.edge.driver`.

**Note** :- The **Default** installed location of the `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` :-

```
for 64 bit is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Driver
for 32 bit is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Web Driver
```

Hope it will work...:)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I matched up my build number to the edge driver version, but I still had the driver freeze during Selenium's initialisation process :/

Comment: It may not matter, but in my situation I had to put the Edge webdriver in the root "C:\" and pass the file path and it started working after reading all of this.

Comment: Kevin is correct. the driver needs to be in the windows PATH in order to execute.

Comment: @JohnPeters The output window doesn't show anything when navigating because it never finishes initialising :/ it just gets stuck on the MSN homepage

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your system does not match the webdriver version... Determine which release of Windows 10 you are using... then go here and download same release..
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver

[image: Vesions]

**Here's what the error looks like when the versions don't match.**

**Selenium will Hang**

```
 EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
 options.PageLoadStrategy = EdgePageLoadStrategy.Eager;
 RemoteWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
 driver.Url = "http://bing.com/";
```

Results in this exception with Edge still up and on the Bing page

[image: NoSuch Driver]

**Exception Thrown**

changing the code to this, with no options:

```
  var driver = new EdgeDriver();
  driver.Url = "http://bing.com/";
```

Results in this:

Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WebDriver.dll

And this in the console.[image: Forcibly Closed]

Something's not right with the MicrosoftWebDriver.Exe which was downloaded from here.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212 and installed into the Program Files folder by default.  Here's screenshot of add/remove programs. System is Windows 10 PRO 64 bit.

[image]

Note I did not try the 32 bit version