# Unable to launch URL in edge browser - Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to automate in Microsoft edge browser. I referred to the below links to do it and I am able to launch the browser, but it's failing to launch the URL. Can someone please help me.

Selenium Java version : 2.53.1
Tried with both of the edge drivers(insider version and webdriver), one returned null exception and not launching any browser and the other is returning unknown error after launching the browser.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Code referred from:
stackoverflow.com/questions/31991309/selenium-on-windows-10-edge-browser

Comment: Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865751/selenium-with-microsoft-edge-driver-never-finishes-initialising/37946776#37946776...

Comment: Thanks, but instead it worked for me downgrading driver version !

Answer (score 2):

You would need to download the correct version of Edge Driver based on the OS build number. I faced this issue when I used Edge driver version which was different from my build number.

Follow the below steps (I have tried this with Selenium 3.0 Beta1 and its working fine)

Use the steps given below -

1. Go to Start > Settings > System > About and note down the OS Build number
2. Download the proper version of the driver from this link - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
3. If the file that's downloaded is .msi, then install it to get the .exe driver. For one of the release, direct .exe can be downloaded.
4. Once the MicrosoftWebDriver.exe is downloaded, we can use it in our test script using either System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "driver location") or using environment variable

Sample Script :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"); //put actual location
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.get("your link");
```

Refer this article for detailed information: http://automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-launch-microsoft-edge-with-microsoftwebdriver/

Comment: Just one point. Instead of checking OS build number, go for Microsoft Edge Version and accordingly download the driver. I am telling this for the latest Microsoft Edge having chromium base.

Answer (score 0):

Note : Edge browser version should be 18 or 19

This solution worked for me was by enabling Developer Mode in Windows OS:

Go to Settings -> Windows Update settings ->For Developers  -> Enable Developer Mode

Run Test Script :

```
public class IETest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {`enter code here`


        WebDriver obj=new EdgeDriver();;
        obj.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```